# Leaving and Re-entering Canada in order to reset 6 month limit

Tags: visas, canada, multiple-entry, visa-extensions

My father plans to visit me in Canada for nine months. He has a multiple entry visa for both the US as well as Canada.

He is a Romanian Citizen and has a V1 Multiple Entry Visa for Canada.

After his fifth month of stay, I wish to drive him to US for one day and re-enter back in Canada.

Will this allow him to stay for six more months? Is it the same thing as you enter through an airport, you get six months of stay as a tourist ?

Comment: You're proposing for your father to do a visa run.  Which may work but may backfire in a bad way. http://www.canadavisa.com/canada-immigration-discussion-board/visa-run-t171097.0.html

Comment: He's romanian and he has a V1 multiple entry tourist visa.

Comment: @Karlson I have read the topic you posted. I think there is little chance for him to be denied re-entry in Canada. So worst case scenario he will have his initial 6 month limit and he will be able to apply for an extension of his tourist visa. Thanks

Comment: @Ionut He's welcome to take a chance and the potential consequences.

Comment: The key thing here is "he may be able to *apply* for a new visa". If he has a visa which grants him six months, he can only stay for six months. To stay longer than that he needs to make an application for extension, not just do a day trip to the US.

Comment: Also how long did he ask to stay when he applied for the visa? And does the visa indicate a length of stay?

Comment: @DJClayworth He applied for a multiple entry visa demanding for a six months stay. The visa does not indicate the length of the stay

Comment: Finally, I will follow your advice and apply for a two months extension.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you arrive in Canada on a tourist visa, [the immigration officer will tell you how long you can stay](http://can-am.gc.ca/visas/trv-after-receiving_vrt-apres-recevoir.aspx?lang=eng). Six months is normal, but it may be less; and unless you specifically asked for it, it is unlikely you will be granted a stay of longer than six months.

If you want to stay longer than what is granted, you need to [apply for an extension to your visa](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/extend-stay.asp). Leaving and re-entering the country will have no effect on visa validity.

Comment: Canada, like the US, requires visas to be valid only upon entry. A visitor whois applying to stay longer than originally permitted is applying to extend status, not to extend visa validity.