# Extension of stay as visitor in Canada with US visitor visa

Tags: visas, usa, canada, multiple-entry

I am on visitor visa in Canada now since 5 months & holding US visitor visa also. Both are multiple entry visas. I am planning to go to US for leisure 2-3 days by road.

Do I have to request for extension when I come to Canada border or is there any hassle? If approve, can I stay for another 6 months in Canada?
.

Answer (score 1):

> [If you want to extend your stay in Canada, you must apply to do so](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/extend/visa.asp). Check your temporary resident status to make sure you apply before the expiry date. This will be on your study or work permit, the stamp in your passport or, if you do not have a stamp in your passport, 6 months from the day you entered Canada. **You should apply 30 days before your status expires to**:
>
> - extend your visitor, student or work status,
> - change your permit type (for example, from a study permit to a work permit) or
> - change your permit condition(s) (for example, if you are studying and you want to change schools, or if you are working and you want to change jobs).

[As @DJClayworth noted in this accepted SETravel answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34234/leaving-and-re-entering-canada-in-order-to-reset-6-month-limit) (emphasis mine):

> If you want to stay longer than what is granted, you need to apply for an extension to your visa. **Leaving and re-entering the country will have no effect on visa validity**.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question as it doesn't address the effect of a short trip to the United States.

Comment: The answer you quote uses incorrect terminology. Visitors to Canada need a valid visa only when they enter. Visitors can apply to extend their *status,* not the (irrelevant) validity of their visa. I see nothing in the links supporting that answer to support the position that a trip to the US and reentry into Canada doesn't result in a fresh period of admission. In other words, the text you emphasized appears to be incorrect.

Comment: @phoog wouldn't it amount to a visa run?

Comment: Well, yes, it would. But I haven't seen any material concerning Canada's attitude towards visa runs.  Maybe a fresh inspection at the border is as acceptable as an in-country application for extension of status.

Comment: @phoog my reasoning is why would Canada include the visitor status in the requirement to extend otherwise.

Comment: Because people should be able to apply to extend their status even if they are unable to travel to the US.

Comment: well I think,my question is still unclear! - hear in detail. - Hear visa category is Visitor & multiple entry. Leaving Canada & entering US is the subject of re-validation ? If Leaving and re-entering the country will have no effect on visa validity then why do we need to take US visa & they stamp on passport ?

Comment: So is it consider for extension ?